# Is $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})[T,T^{-1}]$ a DVR?

Tags: commutative-algebra, irreducible-polynomials, local-rings

I want to check if $R = (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})[T,T^{-1}]$ is a DVR.

What I tried is showing that/ checking if $R$ is a local noetherian integrally closed domain, with precisely two prime ideals, the zero ideal and the maximal ideal.
However, I already get stuck at the integrally closed part.

How should I do this, resp. is there an easier way to check if $R$ is a DVR?

Comment: For any maximal ideal $m\subset k[T]$ then $k[T]_m=(k[T]-m)^{-1}k[T]$  is a DVR. The only one which is not of this form but still containing $k$ and with fraction field $k(T)$ is $k[T^{-1}]_{(T^{-1})}$.

Comment: R is definitely not local!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ring $R = (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})[T]$ is a polynomial ring over a field, so it's a Principal Ideal Domain.

The ring $B = (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})[T,T^{-1}]$ (known as the ring of Laurent polynomials over $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$), is the localization of $R$ at the multiplicative set generated by $T$.  Localizations of PIDs are still PIDs, so $B$ is a PID.  In particular $B$ is *locally* a DVR.  But $B$ has infinitely many prime ideals, so it's far from local, and certainly not a DVR.  To be precise, the prime ideals of $B$ are in one-to-one correspondence with the prime ideals of $R$ that don't contain $T$.  The only prime ideal of $R$ that contains $T$ is $(T)$.